# @fatnlazycat/react-native-recaptcha-v3 jest error in react native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am facing below error in react native jest while using @fatnlazycat/react-native-recaptcha-v3  package for implementing reCaptcha in react native application
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InRD2.png)
please help me out here!!!Thankyou